# PHP preg_match - match a keyword that is completely on its own only?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I match a keyword that is completely on its own?

For instance I only want to match `hello` in a string like these,

```
/say/hello/world/
/say/hello/
```

but **not** in these,

```
/say/helloworld/
/say/hello-world/
/say/hello+world/
/say_hello_world/
```

So far with this pattern,

```
var_dump(preg_match('~.*?(?=hello)~i', $string)); // int 1
```

It matches all of them!

I only want `/something/hello/world/` to be `int 1` - is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the lookahead to include the slashes as well:

```
~.*?(?=/hello/)~i
```

Code:

```
var_dump(preg_match('~.*?(?=/hello/)~i', $string));
```

- [Working demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/219024)
- [Regex101 demo with explanation](http://regex101.com/r/yB4vG2/1)

Comment: I get this error `Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '.' found in ` then it does not match `/say/hello/`

Comment: @tealou: I didn't include the delimiter in the answer. You need to use `~.*?(?=/hello/)~i`.

Comment: @tealou: Please see the updated answer; I've added code and a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with lookarounds:

```
(?<=/)hello(?=/)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cQ5hX2/2)

**Code:**

```
if ( preg_match_all('~(?<=/)hello(?=/)~i', $string, $m) )
   print_r($m);
```

Comment: I get this error `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'h' in..` then it does not match `/say/hello/`